# Duda con edición de archivos TXT En java con Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy haciendo un programa en JAVA que abre un archivo de texto de unos notas musicales y edita unos renglones específicos para crear el mismo archivo pero con el doble de duración para una mejor edicion de las notas , el archivo es de este tipo
uso la clase .io de JAVA
:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito cambiar los valores de Lenght y Tempo al doble lo hago con los siguientes metodos de la siguiente manera:

```
      public static String reemplazar(String cadena, String busqueda, String reemplazo) {
  return cadena.replaceAll(busqueda, reemplazo);
}
    public static void doublar(){
  String Tempo="",Length="";
        double d;
         File archivo = null;
      FileReader fr = null;
      BufferedReader br = null;

      try {
        
          System.out.println("hoooooo");
         archivo = new File ("C:\\Users\\pedro\\Desktop\\prueba.ust");
    

      br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(archivo), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
         // Lectura del fichero
         String linea;
         while((linea=br.readLine())!=null){
        
          if (linea.contains("Tempo")){
            
                Tempo = linea.split("=")[1]; 
                d=Double.parseDouble(Tempo);
                d=d*2;
                linea=reemplazar(linea,Tempo,String.valueOf(d));
                System.out.println("\n\n\n"+linea);
          }
          
           if (linea.contains("Length")){
            
                Length = linea.split("=")[1]; 
                d=Double.parseDouble(Length);
                d=d*2;
                linea=reemplazar(linea,Length,String.valueOf(d));
                System.out.println("\n\n\n"+linea);
          }
          
         }
         
         
      }
      catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
      }finally{
         // En el finally cerramos el fichero, para asegurarnos
         // que se cierra tanto si todo va bien como si salta 
         // una excepcion.
         try{                    
            if( null != fr ){   
               fr.close();     
            }                  
         }catch (Exception e2){ 
            e2.printStackTrace();
        
        
         }}
        
        
        
        
        
        
   }
```

Al reemplazarlo no se guarda en el archivo y la verdad no se si es correcta mi manera, ¿alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que estás guardando el texto ya editado en la variable **linea**, parece ser que solo lo estás doblando en la variable y no lo estás guardando ya que solo está sacando el texto del archivo txt y después lo está editando, pero en ningún momento estás tratando con los datos dentro del archivo de texto.

Deberías crear primero una variable donde se guardarán los datos que estás mostrando con tu variable **linea**.

```
// Lectura del fichero
     String linea;

     //Nuevo String
     String texto_editado = "";

     while((linea=br.readLine())!=null){
    
      if (linea.contains("Tempo")){
        
            Tempo = linea.split("=")[1]; 
            d=Double.parseDouble(Tempo);
            d=d*2;
            linea=reemplazar(linea,Tempo,String.valueOf(d));
            System.out.println("\n\n\n"+linea);

            //Aquí guardará dentro de tu nuevo string cada línea ya editada
            texto_editado = texto_editado + "\n\n\n" + linea;
            //También puedes usar el método append
            //texto_editado.append("\n\n\n" + linea);
      }
      
       if (linea.contains("Length")){
        
            Length = linea.split("=")[1]; 
            d=Double.parseDouble(Length);
            d=d*2;
            linea=reemplazar(linea,Length,String.valueOf(d));
            System.out.println("\n\n\n"+linea);

            //Aquí realiza el mismo procedimiento de arriba
            texto_editado = texto_editado + "\n\n\n" + linea;
      }

//Al terminar el while, deberás guardar los datos en tu archivo txt usando la variable que acabamos de crear

try {
  FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\pedro\\Desktop\\prueba.ust");
  myWriter.write(texto_editado);
  myWriter.close();
  System.out.println("Archivo escrito correctamente");
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error");
  e.printStackTrace();
}
      
     }
```